# opencv matrix brace operator

Tags: opencv, matrix, operator-keyword

I've noticed in many examples/tutorials that people use the brace operator "()" for matrix access, which is confusing for me in some cases.

The question is:
Let's assume we have a n*m matrix (3x4, for example) named M. What elements will be returned by accessing it via "M(0)", or "M(1)", or any other singular parameter inside the braces? I thought that you are supposed to specify both the row and the column (like "M(0,1)" or something like that).

Comment: Could you point out one example of that usage?

Comment: `Mat_<double> X(4,1);
Mat_<double> X_(4,1);

(...)

// A is a 4x3 matrix, B is a 4x1 matrix
cv::solve(A,B,X_,DECOMP_SVD);

X(0) = X_(0); X(1) = X_(1); X(2) = X_(2); X(3) = 1.0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from OpenCV 2.4.2

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat_<_Tp>::operator ()(int i0, int i1)
{
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat_<_Tp>::operator ()(int i0)
{
    return this->at<_Tp>(i0);
}
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat_<_Tp>::operator ()(int i0, int i1, int i2)
{
    return this->at<_Tp>(i0, i1, i2);
}
```

and this is definition for `Mat::at(int i0)` which `Mat_` publicly inherits from `Mat`

```
template<typename _Tp> inline const _Tp& Mat::at(int i0) const
{
    if( isContinuous() || size.p[0] == 1 )
        return ((const _Tp*)data)[i0];
    if( size.p[1] == 1 )
        return *(const _Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0);
    int i = i0/cols, j = i0 - i*cols;
    return ((const _Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i))[j];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What you see there is **linear index access** - namely directly accessing the memory in a linear way.

In a matrix, all elements are stored in one big block of memory, each row following after the previous one. This is why, if you want to access an element at the position `(i, j)` you write somethink like

```
elem = matrix(j + rowWidth*i)
```

But you could simply access it as

```
elem = matrix(k)
```

This is useful when you don't care about the row/col position, by example when you sum up all the elements in a matrix:

```
count = width*height;
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    sum+=matrix(i);
```

Or when you have precalculated linear indices.

Beware that this technique can create some of the craziest bugs if the matrix happen not to be stored in a continuous block of memory - by example a region of interest in a bigger matrix. Always check `if (myMat.isContinuous())` before using linear indices!

Comment: What if I have something like "M.at<double>(0)" or "M.at<double>(0)" ? Opencv reference dosumentation states that "at" method requires a 2d point or two indexes (for row and column). But, apparently, the code I found uses only 1 parameter and works successfully. I don't understand what happens behind the scenes: which matrix element exactly is accesses in this case?

Comment: There are two `at<>` operators, one of them is probably not documented, and it works as explained above

Comment: How about when the argument to the () operator is of type cv::Rect?